# Get three maximum number in array PHP

Tags: php

Can anyone help me? I want to display the three highest number between value in an array.

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0.00
    [1] => 0.00
    [2] => 0.00
    [3] => 0.00
    [4] => 0.00
    [5] => 0.00
    [6] => 1.00
    [7] => 3.00
    [8] => 0.00
    [9] => 5.00
    [10] => 2.00
    [11] => 0.00
)
```

I want to get the following result, just the three highest number in an array

```
Array
(       
    [7] => 3.00
    [9] => 5.00
    [10] => 2.00

)
```

Comment: Have you looked into sorting the data?

Comment: Show us what you have tried, your best attempt (code). Where are you stuck? Please read [ask]

Answer (score 0):

you can use asort() like below:

```
$array = array
(
    0 => 0.00,
    1 => 0.00,
    2 => 0.00,
    3 => 0.00,
    4 => 0.00,
    5 => 0.00,
    6 => 1.00,
    7 => 3.00,
    8 => 0.00,
    9 => 5.00,
    10 => 2.00,
    11 => 0.00
);
asort($array);
$array = array_reverse($array,true);
$array = array_chunk($array, 3);
foreach ($array[0] as $key => $val) {
    echo "$key = $val\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Best is to sort the array first and then pick first 3 elements from an array.

```
<?php

$array = [1,2,5,6,3,7,8];
$sortedArray = arsort($array); 
// arsort sorts an array based on values in descending order. 

$highestElements = array_slice($sortedArray,0, 3, true);
// array_slice returns selected parts of an array.
```

You can change the third parameter of array_slice to number of top elements you want from an array.

**Reference:**

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php